# How to connect to mysql instance using cloud shell in Google cloud?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

We created a MySQL instance in GCP. While connecting to this instance using Google cloud shell, we're getting this error:

> Host 35.200.234.37 is not allowed to connect to this type of mysql server.

We are using Python to connect it to db.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally it's helpful to include the code you're using which isn't working in your question. In this case, can you include an example of how you're attempting to connect to the DB, with passwords, and IP addresses removed/replaced?

Comment: Did you see the following ... https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip